# How to run tests on each hot recompile using SBT?

Tags: unit-testing, playframework, sbt

I'm running my Play Framework app using the command `sbt run`

When I change something in the code, it will "hot recompile" and serve my updated app.

I would like to run my unit test on each hot recompile.

I have tried things like
`sbt test run` but it will only run the test once. Then, all the other code change trigger "hot recompile" but no unit test.

I also tried `sbt ~test run` but it will wait for code change forever and never launch the app.

Is there a way to configure SBT so that it will always run the command "test" each time there is a hot recompile?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The closest I could get was running `sbt` and then using the command `~ ;test;run`, which will run the tests and then launch the app in a continuous cycle (as long as there are changes) but still requires you to shut down the app with Ctrl-D to get back to running the tests.

My initial approach was trying to disable auto-reloading, but it [appears to be hard-coded](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/4c17455e28f056ffcdcd91d151ed8dff605a3146/framework/src/play-server/src/main/scala/play/core/server/DevServerStart.scala#L93), and even that wouldn't be enough on it's own, as you'd need whatever the auto-reload hook uses to shut down the app with each change. So... technically possible, but not without creating a custom sbt task.

Comment: Ah :( That's bad. That would have been a very nice thing for TDD. I wonder how complicated it would be to create a custom sbt task. I guess detecting code change and doing hot recompile is not a trivial thing... Thanks

Comment: I recommend you ask the Play team to consider this use case.